# F# class type with unusual construction feature

Tags: f#

I have a class type defined like this:

```
type T1(?maybei1: int, ?maybei2: int) =
```

All the following work:

```
let t11 = T1(1, 2)
let t12 = T1(1)
let t13 = T1()
```

but this one doesn't (as expected):

```
let tuple = (1, 2)
let t14 = T1 tuple //error: expected int but given int * int
```

on the other hand, if I define my type as:

```
type T2(i1: int, i2: int) =
```

then I can construct an instance by a tuple

```
let tuple = (1, 2)
let t24 = T2 tuple //ok
```

but I lose the optionals:

```
let t22 = T2(1) //error
let t23 = T2() //error
```

I tried with an additional constructor:

```
type T3(?maybei1: int, ?maybei2: int) =
    new (i1: int, i2: int) = T3(i1, i2)

type T4(i1: int, i2: int) =
    new (?maybei1: int, ?maybei2: int) =
```

but I couldn't get a version that I can instantiate with both optional parameters and a tuple.
Any idea (without delegation, encapsulation or inheritance, just one type)?

**EDIT**

Tomas Petricek found a way to make it work; good enough.

However, as he also mentions, there is still something that, imho, doesn't sound entirely right.
For example, without the overload constructor that takes a tuple, we end up to a situation where:

```
let tup = (1, 2)

let t1 = T (1, 2) //ok
let t2 = T tup //error
```

In the first instantiation, the compiler maps the two parameters into option types as expected by the constructor, I would expect the same occurs in the second instantiation.
Does anyone know whether there is a reason why it isn't like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add an overloaded constructor that takes an explicit tuple as its only argument, then all ways of creating an instance work:

```
type T(?maybei1: int, ?maybei2: int) =
    new (tup:int*int) = T(fst tup, snd tup)
    member x.Values = maybei1, maybei2

T(1)
T(1, 2)
T(maybei2=2)
let tup = (1, 2)
T tup
```

I'm honestly not entirely sure what the rules for passing tuples as arguments to methods of multiple parameters are - this is somewhat tricky. Logically, you could think of members as taking a tuple, but this is not the whole story because of optional parameters and compilation (it gets compiled as a normal method), so the behaviour is somewhat subtle. But defining an explicit overload taking a tuple (which will be compiled as taking `System.Tuple`) does the trick!

Comment: Nice work. I tried various approaches and didn't find any that worked, but I missed that one. Good to know.

Comment: As far as I've been able to deduce from experimentation in the past, as long as you stay away from anything that isn't functional - optional, byref, ref, that sort of thing - then whether it's a method or a function, they always use the curried form, and there's no getting away from it. The so called tupled form is technically just the curried form with a single tuple as parameter. Only a convention.